# How do I create an IMarker in a standalone SWT-application

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I need to create an IMarker-object for input to MarkerAnnotation.
When doing it from within an Eclipse-plugin, itś easy to get a IResource and do createMarker on that, but within my standalone SWT application I find it hard to get hold of a IResource.
Is there any way to get hold of a IResource within my SWT-application?, or is it possible to create the IMarker without using an IResource?

Answer (score 1):

But how can you get a `MarkerAnnotation` in a standalone application? It's in `org.eclipse.ui.texteditor` package, which is provided by `org.eclipse.ui.editors`, which depends on `org.eclipse.core.runtime`, `org.eclipse.ui`, etc.

At any rate, look at [methods returning `IMarker`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/class-use/IMarker.html). There doesn't seem to be anything suitable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding an answer my own question.
It seems very hard to create IMarkers in standalone SWT, as Alexey pointed out.

However, the answer from Emil Crumhorn in this forum post effectively solved my AnnotationMarker-problem: http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t30082.html

It shows how to create annotations (like the one used in a Eclipse-editor) in SWT code.